# How to use downloaded font in css

Tags: css, fonts, tumblr, truetype

Very entry-level here.
I have a `.ttf` font file I'd like to use for my blog, but I am unsure of how/where I can get its coding (?). Is this about right?

```
* {
    font-family: 'providence-bold';
    src: url('/font/providence-bold.regular.ttf');
  }
```

feel free to skewer this, as I said I've little idea of what I'm doing.

EDIT: Here is a link to the font I'm trying to use. (If it helps) https://ufonts.com/download/providence-bold.html

Comment: `* { font-family: 'providence-bold'; src: url(<URL_OF_FONT>); }` where font url may be relative or absolute.

Comment: i have no idea what "relative or absolute" means :-( my initial issue was not knowing how/where to get the url of the font im tryna use.

Comment: Where are your css and font files?? Are they inside root or separate folder?

Answer (score 12):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'providence-bold';
  src: url('/font/providence-bold.regular.ttf');
}
```

This is the format I use. Just make sure you're path is correct.

***Side note:** I don't like using underscores (_) and dashes (-) in variables.
It's recommended to get in the habit of writing variables as camelCase or PascalCase.*

Answer (score 5):

I would advice and is a better way to include fonts is by converting it into these formats.

You can get the code from here after you converting your fonts into the formats you wanted -> [link](https://onlinefontconverter.com/)

After you convert your fonts it will produce a rar file extract it you will find the `font.css` where you can find these codes. [image: format selection] [image: extracted rar file] [image: Finally the font.css]

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'providence-bold';
src: url('../fonts/providence-bold.eot');
src: url('../fonts/providence-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/providence-bold.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/providence-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/providence-bold.svg#providence-bold') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
```

Be sure to check your url to the fonts' location.

Comment: wow.. this is so in depth! thanks so much for these steps. I went ahead to add the css code to my blogs "theme".. but, it seems a different type of hmtl is needed for the sites formatting. i tried following this (http://academyoftumblr.tumblr.com/post/31791227786/how-to-add-custom-fonts-on-your-theme) quite outdated tutorial to get the correct result, but im a tad confused. are you familiar with css of this sort?

Comment: unfortunately, the font im trying to use isnt available via google fonts :( this makes getting the URL pretty difficult. (let me reiterate, this stiff is a foreign language to me!) would it help if i showed snippets of the "themes code"?

Comment: Yup add your snippet here we'll help you to sort out the problem

Comment: ok, so the sites custom coding system is a bit messy. heres the relevant areas of the (quite long) code i could be messing up in:

Comment: <head>
@font-face {
font-family: 'providence-bold';
src: url('../fonts/providence-bold.eot');
src: url('../fonts/providence-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/providence-bold.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/providence-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/providence-bold.svg#providence-bold') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

Comment: so, so sorry about the poor comment formatting. basically, any aspects of code thatll edit the blogs appearnce have to go under <head>, with a seperate section for custom ccs. basically, is the coding i have under <head> correct? im unsure of what to type for the custom css

Comment: heres what my page is lookin like with the current coding: https://imgur.com/a/T2rTxTM. the rest of my blog is showing up fine, posts+links an everything, but the block of font coding is displayed up top.

Comment: You cannot install font files to your tumblr. You can only add them if they are served from somewhere (like googlefonts). `src:url('../fonts')` is looking for a file relative to your tumblr url, no such folder exists and you cannot create it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the link to the font from the url provided here:

`https://ufonts.com/download/providence-bold.html`

if you add them like this `../providence-bold.html` they are relative to your html document. So would need to be installed on your server `http://yourname.tumblr.com` or whatever.

If you change the urls to point to the resource at ufonts, then it should work.

So

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'providence-bold';
src: url('https://ufonts.com/fonts/providence-bold.eot');
src: url('https://ufonts.com/fonts/providence-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('https://ufonts.com/fonts/providence-bold.woff') format('woff'),
      url('https://ufonts.com/fonts/providence-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('https://ufonts.com/fonts/providence-bold.svg#providence-bold') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
```

However these resources must exist at the ufonts url. If it is just a place to download the ttf file, this will not work. They have to be served from somewhere, and tumblr will not allow you to upload font files to their servers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get fonts in a proper format. Youca n download them in the required .ttf format at such websites as https://fontsly.com/gothic/celtic or youc an use some converters.